# How do I limit the number objects I iterate over when Linq is not supported?

Tags: c#, office-interop

How do I limit my foreach loop to the first 500 emails?  It seems Linq and Lambda is not supported on emailFolder.Items. Is there another approach that I should be taking?

```
Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.NameSpace outlookNs = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Outlook.MAPIFolder emailFolder = outlookNs.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

foreach(Object item in emailFolder.Items)
{        
   Outlook.MailItem _item = (Outlook.MailItem)item;
   Console.WriteLine(_item.SenderEmailAddress + " " + _item.Subject + "\n" + _item.Body);
}
```

Comment: What [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx)  is `emailFolder.Items` and what Type of items are contained within that collection?  I'm betting you can [Cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341406(v=vs.100).aspx) them to a type you can use Linq with.

Comment: Use a for loop that only iterates 500 times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linq only works on types that are implement the interface `IEnumerable<T>`. Older collections implement the non-generic interface `IEnumerable`, which does not work with Linq. There are some extensions methods which "convert" these collections to linqable collections:

To convert `Items` to a something linqable, use:

```
emailFolder.Items.Cast<Outlook.MailItem>()....
```

*** EDITED after suggestion of Spender & Alexei ***

If you are using the try-catch to suppress an invalid cast, resulting in only items of a specific type, try:

```
emailFolder.Items.OfType<Outlook.MailItem>()....
```

This could lead to:

```
Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.NameSpace outlookNs = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Outlook.MAPIFolder emailFolder = outlookNs.GetDefaultFolder  (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

foreach(Outlook.MailItemitem _item in emailFolder.Items.OfType<Outlook.MailItem>().Take(500))
{
    Console.WriteLine(_item.SenderEmailAddress + " " + _item.Subject + "\n" + _item.Body);
}
```

Comment: +1. Much shorter than manual `foreach`/`for`. Consider if `Enumerable.OfType<T>` is more appropriate than `Enumerable.Cast<T>` (depending if you expect all items to be of given type or just some).

Comment: Cast might break because there's no guarantee that all items are mail items.

Comment: @spender: True... but the given example of the OP will also break, that is why I choose `Cast<T>`. If you do not want it to break, `OfType<T>` is a good solution, as Alexei stated.

Comment: Point taken but...It looks to me as if any non-mail items get swallowed by the terrible exception handling, os OfType would be closer to OPs original code.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`.OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method to grab a typed `IEnumerable<Outlook.MailItem>` of all the `Outlook.MailItem` instances in the `Items` collection.

```
mapifolder.Items.OfType<Outlook.MailItem>()
```

...and you can return to Linq-world!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you're using .NET framework version 4 or later, you should make sure the next line is in the file header (the "using" section):

```
using System.Linq;
```

Otherwise, there's always the following:

```
int count=0;
foreach(Object item in emailFolder.Items)
{
    try
    {

        Outlook.MailItem _item = (Outlook.MailItem)item;
        Console.WriteLine(_item.SenderEmailAddress + " " + _item.Subject + "\n" + _item.Body);

        ++count;
        if (count == 500)
            break;

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    }
```

}